# <textarea> auto reset to the top when set a new value

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

**HTML :**

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="50">
Cake cupcake sesame snaps. Cookie marshmallow bonbon faworki pie caramels. 
Icing tootsie roll jelly-o pudding bear claw. Candy topping fruitcake jelly...
{Type something after this..}
</textarea>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('textarea').on("keyup", function(e) {
      var val = $('<div/>').html($(this).val());
      $(this).val(val.text().replace(/'/g,"’"));
});
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/u6PmN/

I have a `<textarea>` in fixed size , When I type after content is full and I using jQuery to replace some string so...

`<textarea>` is reset to the top

Any idea ?

---

**Update :**

I do like this

```
$('textarea').on("keyup", function(e) {
    var oldVal = $(this).val();
    var newVal = $('<div/>').html($(this).val());
    var newVal = newVal.text().replace(/'/g,"’");
    if(oldVal!=newVal) {
      $(this).val(newVal);
    }
});
```

Just put a new replaced value when value has replaced

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to scroll to bottom on appending the string. here is my code..

```
$('textarea').on("keyup", function(e) {
      var val = $('<div/>').html($(this).val());
      $(this).val(val.text().replace(/'/g,"’"));   
$(this).animate({
    scrollTop:$(document).height()
},1000)
});
```

here the textarea is set to scroll .